# iPhone app says "Installing" instead of "app Name" in IPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios7, iphone-5

When i am moving app from iTunes to iPhone then successfully installed app on my iPhone5.But when press on my app then immediately change app name to "installing" and also cannot open the app.But in my iPhone4s doesn't have this problem.This problem existing only my iPhone5. Recently i updated my iPhone(4S & 5) to iOS7.Please help me

Comment: if it is an _Enterprise_ or _AdHoc Distribution_, your device's `UDID` must be in the _Distribution Profile_, otherwise you cannot run the app on the actual device.

Comment: @holex I have run the app with appstore provisional certificate.

Answer (score 0):

open the app store in the iPhone 5 go to update then purchased section and check if u can see the apps there  that u installed from itunes show open or cloud download ?

Also make sure u using the latest iTunes version.

I believe the issue from itunes as it is not installing the apps correctly.